# avoiding repeated rule while reading xml

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am doing yahoo API program where i am getting result as XML format and fetching values from that xml files using the rule name. But in my case the xml file looks like this.

```
<person>
  <first>Kiran</first>
  <first>sam</first>
  <url>www.aaaaaaaaddd.com</url>
  <last>Pai</last>
  <age>22</age>
  <url>www.ajsajha.com</url?
</person>
<person>
  <first>Kiran</first>
  <first>tom</first>
  <url>www.aaaaasdadd.com</url>
  <last>Pai</last>
  <age>22</age>
  <url>www.wqeqwjha.com</url>
</person>
```

In this i want to take values from the following rules : first, url, lat, age. But i want to take only one value from the rule first, url.

```
if(e.getElementsByTag("url")!=null)
              {
                  itemStringBuilder.append(e.getElementsByTag("url").text());

              }
```

when i use this code i am getting both the url values. How can i check and avoid the second one and just take the first.

Comment: Are you using plain java DOM parser? or any thir party libraries? Because in java there is no method called "getElementsByTag" it is "getElementsByTagName"

Answer (score 2):

```
Elements urls = e.getElementsByTag("url"):
if (urls != null)
{
    itemStringBuilder.append(urls.first().text());
}
```

Use `first()` on the Elements gotten. One call to get is more efficient.

[Javadoc](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) is your best friend.